# Array initialization throwing a compiler error

Tags: c++, arrays, templates

I'm trying to initialize an `std::array` based on the length of a variadic template. My code is posted below, I'd like the array to hold `int`s, with enough room to fit one `int` per parameter passed in `Types`.

The `sizeof...()` operator should do what I want, if I'm not mistaken, so I would think that the following code is valid.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


template<typename Type, typename ...Types>
class Object{
    public:
        std::array<int, sizeof...(Types)> loadedValues;
};



int main(){
    auto k = new Object<int, float, int, int>();
}
```

However, I'm running into a mysterious compiler error:

```
error: ‘Object<Type, Types>::values’ has incomplete type
std::array<int, sizeof...(Types)> values;
```

(GCC 12)

I'm still relatively new to metaprogramming, so it could just be an error in my code that I haven't caught, but if anyone could provide insight on why compilation is failing, that would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Forgetting to include the header `array` will result in an incomplete type error. Although GCC 12.2 issues a warning:

```
<source>:1:1: note: 'std::array' is defined in header '<array>'; did you forget to '#include <array>'?
  +++ |+#include <array>
```

As shown on Godbolt here: https://godbolt.org/z/6nfTTKre, however, this may be obscured or harder to find if there are a number of templates (My case), and there is a long list of errors/warnings, or depending on your settings.

I wrote this question before checking Godbolt, which revealed the error quite quickly, so I figured a Q&A style question would be appropriate should anyone run into a similar error.

Comment: Good of you to pay it forward and write  clear and concise answer. I recommend updating the question slightly to include a [mre] that shows that <array> was not included. This will allow future askers with a similar problem to be able to better make the connections between the question and the answer.

Comment: @user4581301 Would you recommend just having a simple ```main``` function and some dummy headers ```iostream``` (etc.) to show that ```array``` is absent? First time doing a Q&A